# Network manager show eth0 connection but no interenet access

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ethernet, networkmanager

I tried `ping www.google.com` and `ping 8.8.8.8` and access the web browser manually, resulting in "server couldn't connect".

I have 3 connections via eth0, wlan0 and wlan1(through USB) , eth0 **doesn't** have internet access and when I activate wlan0 or wlan1 with eth0 I dont have internet access, but when I activate **only wlan0 or wlan1** I **do**, when I activate **eth0 alone**, I **dont** have internet access, so maybe something in eth0 configurations?

I do get an IP for eth0:
[image: ipconnection]

[image: routing]

I tried disabling Wi-Fi cause i've read somewhere that wlan0/1 could be the default access and avoiding internet connection from eth0,but it didn't work also.

My /etc/network/interfaces file:

> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback

My etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file:

> [main]
> plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
>
> [ifupdown]
> managed=false

WireShark shows no DHCP ack from router / server:
[image: Wireshark]

I also tried pinging to address & IP:(canceled the ping 8.8.8.8 for taking too long)
[image: Pinging]

Comment: Did you check the interfaces with `wireshark` or `tcpdump`? This way you could detect whether the interfaces are sending packages or the response is lost. What happens if you set the interface with `ping -I eth0 www.google.de`? (@mods: this should be a comment, but I don't have the rep. I'll update this answer depending on OP's comments)

Comment: Superuser is mostly for windows if you want linux related question, go to linux & unix. You may find better answers there.

Comment: @answerSeeker I did try that a week ago, no one was able to answer my post, I deleted it and came here hoping for an answer, I also tried searching for a problem similar to mine, the solutions didnt help.

Comment: @r3r57 I checked the interfaces with wireshark , posted the results in my question above, also tried pinging I have posted the results above . I have updated my files , I changed the eth0 to get an IP not automatically by using NetworkManager, you can see all the changes I made in the question, What do you think I can do to solve the problem?